# Angular material form styling/animations missing in production

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular2-forms

Taking the `mat-slide-toggle` as an example, locally I see the HTML tag looks like this:

```
<div
  class="mat-slide-toggle-ripple mat-ripple"
  mat-ripple=""
  ng-reflect-centered="true"
  ng-reflect-radius="20"
  ng-reflect-animation="[object Object]"
  ng-reflect-disabled="false"
  ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLLabelElement]">
  <div class="mat-ripple-element mat-slide-toggle-persistent-ripple"></div>
</div>
```

However in production, it's missing the Angular attributes:

```
<div class="mat-slide-toggle-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple="">
  <div class="mat-ripple-element mat-slide-toggle-persistent-ripple"></div>
</div>
```

It looks like this in production: [image: material slider in production]

It looks right locally: [image]

I face the same issue with all the other form elements like `input`. They are missing the `ng*` attributes on the HTML tag in production.

https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started:
I have `import 'hammerjs';` in `main.ts`, imported `BrowserAnimationsModule` in `app.module`, and ran both `npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations` and `npm install --save hammerjs` locally. The `package.json` file is pushed into Git, which production pulls down.

Does anyone know what I'm missing or where to investigate? Maybe I installed some package globally on my desktop and didn't include it in the `package.json`?

### Update

I found that my production build seems to be missing the pre-built 'indigo-pink.css` file.

My `styles.scss` looks like this:

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */

@import "src/assets/fonts/fonts.scss";
@import "src/assets/old_css/some-css.min";
@import "src/assets/old_scss/style";

@import "./src/assets/old_scss/color.scss";
@import "./src/assets/old_scss/variable.scss";

@import "~@ng-select/ng-select/themes/material.theme.css";
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
@import "./src/assets/scss/am.scss";
```

I realized the `ng-reflect` attributes are debug attributes. But I haven't been able to figure out why the pre-built theme isn't being built into the production minimized CSS file.

---

My Angular CLI version on my desktop:

```
Angular CLI: 7.0.5
Node: 11.1.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 7.0.3
... common, compiler, core, forms, http, language-service
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.10.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.13.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.13.8
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.13.8
@angular-devkit/core               7.0.5
@angular-devkit/schematics         7.0.5
@angular/animations                7.2.12
@angular/cdk                       7.3.7
@angular/cli                       7.0.5
@angular/compiler-cli              7.2.9
@angular/flex-layout               7.0.0-beta.24
@angular/material                  7.3.7
@angular/material-moment-adapter   7.3.6
@ngtools/webpack                   7.3.8
@schematics/angular                7.0.5
@schematics/update                 0.10.5
rxjs                               6.3.3
typescript                         3.1.6
webpack                            4.29.0
```

---

My build script:

```
            - echo Installing source NPM dependencies...
            - npm install
            - npm install -g @angular/cli
            - npm install -g gulp

            - echo Build started on `date`
            - ng build --prod --configuration=${BUILD_ENV} --build-optimizer
            - gulp purifyCSS
            // sync S3
```

---

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.12",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.24",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^7.3.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^7.0.3",
    "@fancyapps/fancybox": "^3.5.6",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^2.3.6",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/http-client": "^2.0.0-alpha.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^10.0.2",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "@toverux/ngx-sweetalert2": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/chartist": "^0.9.43",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.11",
    "@types/mixpanel": "^2.14.0",
    "angular-archwizard": "^3.0.0",
    "angular-highcharts": "^6.2.6",
    "angulartics2": "^6.3.0",
    "animate.css": "^3.7.0",
    "chartist": "^0.11.0",
    "chartist-plugin-tooltip": "0.0.11",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "dayjs": "^1.7.7",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "highcharts": "^6.2.0",
    "humanize-duration": "^3.15.3",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "mixpanel-browser": "^2.22.4",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng-animate": "^0.3.4",
    "ng-click-outside": "^4.0.0",
    "ng-scrollreveal": "^2.2.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.0.1",
    "ngx-chartist": "^1.0.3",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^1.0.10",
    "ngx-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.0.3",
    "ngx-modal-dialog": "^3.0.0",
    "ngx-order-pipe": "^2.0.1",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.2.1",
    "ngx-slick": "^0.2.1",
    "ngx-slick-carousel": "^0.4.1",
    "ngx-sweetalert2": "^0.2.7",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "nonblockjs": "^1.0.8",
    "npm": "^6.7.0",
    "pnotify": "^4.0.0-beta.2",
    "rollbar": "^2.4.5",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "scrollreveal": "^3.4.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "sweetalert2": "^7.25.0",
    "validatorjs": "^3.14.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.0.3",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^4.1.2",
    "@types/highcharts": "^5.0.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.4",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/scrollreveal": "0.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-purifycss": "^0.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^2.0.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "ngx-page-scroll": "~5.0.0",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.0.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: whats your angular-cli version?

Comment: @imanshu15 I updated the question to include the version.

Comment: try ng build --prod --build-optimizer=false

Comment: @imanshu15 I can try this, but why does this cause an issue?

Comment: I also updated the post with my build script.

Comment: can you add your package json as well?

Comment: @imanshu15 I updated with the package.json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in [this blog post](https://medium.com/tensult/angular-material-custom-theme-implementation-in-angular-6-d424a2a47e4c).

I did a combination of both these things:

> You can directly include the pre-built angular-material-theme in the styles.css file.
>   `@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';`

Note the lack of "~" in front of "@angular".

> Update the following in angular.json file.
>
> ````
> "styles": [
>   {
>     "input": "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css"
>   },
>   "src/styles.css"
> ] ```
> ````

I had originally tried this but it didn't work:

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css",
  "src/styles.css"
]
```

I'm not sure if both are required. I've noticed blog posts and stackoverflow questions regarding removing the "~" from the import, but I haven't come across `"styles": [ { "input": "node_modules/..." } ]` before. I didn't find this information from the Angular Material docs.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Ripples would not work and tooltips were weirdly styled and would not appear at the right place. It seemed like I was missing all the classes starting with "cdk-".

Adding the following import worked, as @gruuuvy mentioned.

```
@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

It seemed weird to me that I had to import a prebuilt-theme in order for these things to work. I found out, reading the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#defining-a-custom-theme), that I was missing an include which contains all of the basic angular material classes.

```
// Include the common styles for Angular Material. We include this here so that you only
// have to load a single css file for Angular Material in your app.
// Be sure that you only ever include this mixin once!
@include mat-core();
```