# Angular material datepicker opened in wrong position

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material, angular8

I am using datepicker material for an input field.  (angular material v 8.2.3)

```
<input (click)="datePicker.open()" class="form-control" matInput [formControl]="input.controller"
                       [matDatepicker]="datePicker" readonly>
                <mat-datepicker touchUi="false" #datePicker></mat-datepicker>
```

Everything works as expected on local environment: the datepicker is opened below the input field, as expected.
[image]

When running angular with my prod build ( run build:prod   -with webpack ) -the datepicker will be out of position, opening bottom left, after all form fields.

I've noticed that while on local environment, the datepicker has applied mat-calendar-.. classes, .cdk- ..) etc but on inspecting while on prod, those classes are missing.

What could have lead to this behaviour ?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/55602402/3503019 answer your question?

Comment: On my angular project I do not use angular.json nor styles.css.
I am importing indigo-pink.css in my index.ts file in src/adm  ( import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css')   with all other components being under this path)
When using run  'npm run build: prod'  ( which runs webpack.prod.js), it seems that it renders some angular material classes unusable .

Comment: Seems I was able to fix it with adding 
```<link href="https://unpkg.com/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet"> ```
to my html.